# Python: mp3 to alsaaudio through ffmpeg pipe and wave.open(f,'r')

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg

I'm trying to decode mp3 to wav using ffmpeg:

```
import alsaaudio
import wave
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with open('filename.mp3', 'rb') as infile:
    p=Popen(['ffmpeg', '-i', '-', '-f', 'wav', '-'], stdin=infile, stdout=PIPE)
    ...
```

Next i want redirect data from p.stdout.read() to wave.open(file, r) to use readframes(n) and other methods. But i cannot because 'file' in wave.open(file,'r') can be only name of file or an open file pointer.

```
    ...
    file = wave.open(p.stdout.read(),'r')
    card='default'
    device=alsaaudio.PCM(card=card)
    device.setchannels(file.getnchannels())
    device.setrate(file.getframerate())
    device.setformat(alsaaudio.PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE)
    device.setsetperiodsize(320)
    data = file.readframes(320)
    while data:
        device.write(data)
        data = file.readframes(320)
```

I got:

```
TypeError: file() argument 1 must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str
```

So is it possible to handle data from p.stdout.read() by wave.open()?
Making temporary .wav file isn't solution.

Sorry for my english.
Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to **PM 2Ring** for hit about io.BytesIO.

However resulting code does not work.

```
import alsaaudio
import wave
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with open('sometrack.mp3', 'rb') as infile:
        p=Popen(['ffmpeg', '-i', '-', '-f','wav', '-'], stdin=infile , stdout=PIPE , stderr=PIPE)
        fobj = io.BytesIO(p.stdout.read())
fwave = wave.open(fobj, 'rb')
```

Trace:

```
File "./script.py", line x, in <module>
  fwave = wave.open(fobj, 'rb')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wave.py", line x, in open
  return Wave_read(f)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wave.py", line x, in __init__
  self.initfp(f)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wave.py", line x, in initfp
  raise Error, 'not a WAVE file'
wave.Error: not a WAVE file
```

From /usr/lib/python2.7/wave.py:

```
...
self._file = Chunk(file, bigendian = 0)
if self._file.getname() != 'RIFF':
    raise Error, 'file does not start with RIFF id'
if self._file.read(4) != 'WAVE':
    raise Error, 'not a WAVE file'
...
```

Checking has been failed due to 'bad' self._file object.

Inside /usr/lib/python2.7/chunk.py i have found a source of problem:

```
...
try:
    self.chunksize = struct.unpack(strflag+'L', file.read(4))[0]
except struct.error:
    raise EOFError
...
```

Because struct.unpack(strflag+'L', file.read(4))[0] returns 0.
But this function works correct.

As specified [here](http://www.topherlee.com/software/pcm-tut-wavformat.html):

"5-8 bytes - File size(integer)
Size of the overall file - 8 bytes, in bytes (32-bit integer). **Typically, you'd fill this in after creation."**
That's why my script doesn't work. wave.open and other functions cannot handle my file object because self.chunksize = 0. Looks like ffmpeg cannot insert File size when using PIPE.

**SOLUTION**

It's simple.
I've changed init function of Chunk class:

After:

```
...
try:
    self.chunksize = struct.unpack(strflag+'L', file.read(4))[0]
except struct.error:
    raise EOFError
...
```

Before:

```
...
try:
    self.chunksize = struct.unpack(strflag+'L', file.read(4))[0]
    currtell = file.tell()
    if self.chunksize == 0:
        file.seek(0)
        file.read(currtell)
        self.chunksize = len(file.read())-4
        file.seek(0)
        file.read(currtell)
except struct.error:
    raise EOFError
...
```

Of course editing of original module is bad idia. So I've create custom forks for 2 classes Chunk and Wave_read.

Working but unstable full code you can find [here](http://sharetext.org/Kc0y).

Sorry for my awful english.

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting! But you really should post the solution you found as an _answer_, rather than as a modification to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention, the `file` arg to `wave.open(file,'r')` can only be the name of file or an open file pointer. But `p.stdout.read()` is the *contents* of the file `p.stdout` as a string. However, you can't just pass the `p.stdout` file to `wave.open()` because `wave.open()` needs a *seekable* file-like object, and you generally can't `seek()` on a pipe.

But what you *can* do is wrap the bytes you read from `p.stdout.read()` in a [io.BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) object. The resulting object will behave like a file, and it will be seekable.

FWIW, it's not a good idea to use `file` as a variable name as it's the name of a built-in type in Python 2; I guess it's ok to use it Python 3, but I'd still avoid it.

**Warning: untested Python 2.6+ code**

```
fbytes = io.BytesIO(p.stdout.read())
fwave = wave.open(fbytes, 'r')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your audio file to raw audio instead of wav by using `-f s16le` instead of `-f wav` you might not need `wave.open` at all and you can directly stream to ALSA. I only tried this with PyAudio and it worked.